# Comparing self-made O-QPSK signal with Zigbee burst (Q-QPSK acc. to IEEE 802.15.4)

Tags: digital-communications, gnuradio, software-defined-radio

What might be the cause of the worse baseband demodulation result of the bottom VSA screenshot compared to the demodulation result shown in the top screenshot ?

1. Randomized Q-QPSK signal generated by using gnuradio blocks with SamplesPerSymbol = 12, sample rate = 12 Msps, half-sine pulse shape. Transmitted by hackrf-device at fc=2405 MHz:

[image: o-qpsk demod by vsa]

2. Zigbee signal according to IEEE 802.15.4 (OQPSK), created by an USB-CC2531 Zigbee transceiver, captured and cyclic transmitted by hackrf-device at fc=2405 MHz:

[image: zigbee demod by vsa]

The IQ constellation of the Zigbee burst is unstable, the eye pattern is more or less closed, the SNR is quite low, the power spectrum appears noisy compared to the upper O-QPSK signal. I currently rule out an override. The USB-CC2531 transceiver used works perfectly in a Zigbee network environment.

Any thoughs / suggestions to demodulate the shown zigbee burst on the VSA or even with help of gnuradio properly are well appreciated.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "captured and cyclic transmitted"?

Comment: Means, due to the short zigbee burst (e.g. < 2ms) capturing the burst (by hackrf-device), store it in a file (complex float) and "stream" it to the signal analyzer (repetitively) in order to demodulate this signal. Unfortunately, my signal analyzer needs a repetitive/cyclic signal because there are no specific trigger-modes  for burst signals supported. With my O-QPSK signal (top screenshot) it works perfectly so far.

Comment: I suspect your HackRF is distorting the signal on reception, because of malfunction or misconfiguration.